# to_python() and from_db_value() methods overlapping in function?

Tags: python, django

I've been looking at this code example from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects):

```
import re

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

def parse_hand(hand_string):
    """Takes a string of cards and splits into a full hand."""
    p1 = re.compile('.{26}')
    p2 = re.compile('..')
    args = [p2.findall(x) for x in p1.findall(hand_string)]
    if len(args) != 4:
        raise ValidationError(_("Invalid input for a Hand instance"))
    return Hand(*args)

class HandField(models.Field):
    # ...

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is None:
            return value
        return parse_hand(value)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Hand):
            return value

        if value is None:
            return value

        return parse_hand(value)
```

As far as I understand, `from_db_value()` is responsible for turning a string that's coming from the database to the right python type (please correct me if I'm wrong). `to_python()` is **also** responsible for turning a string value into a python type. If we look at the example, the two functions do similar stuff. No, not the exact same stuff, but very similar.

My questions:

1. What is the reason for having two very similar methods on the field?
2. Why does `to_python()` have to be able to handle `value = Hand()`? I thought it was made for turning strings into `Hand` objects. Why does `from_db_value()` **not** need to be able to handle this case?

Comment: `from_db_value()` will be called in all circumstances when the data is loaded from the database, including in aggregates and `values()` calls.

`to_python()` is called by deserialization and during the clean() method used from forms

Comment: Is it correct to say that `from_db_value()` is the function responsible for deserialization in those circumstances?

Comment: `from_db_value()` handles only data from database. `to_python()` also handles form deserialization.

Comment: Yes, it handles data from the database, but in the example above, it's turning that data into the deserialized type, `Hand`. Isn't that what's called deserialisation?

Comment: Yes, `to_python` should also be able to handle correct datatype, i.e. `Hand` in this case. Like the docs say so.

Comment: Validation of a form is split into several steps, which can be customized or overridden:

The `to_python()` method on a Field is the first step in every validation. It coerces the value to a correct datatype and raises `ValidationError` if that is not possible.

Comment: So, `from_db_value()` also does deserialisation?

Comment: from the database as a string or null value to a python value, yes.

Comment: Could you provide examples of when each function is called? For example in the official example: `example = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1); print(example.hand.north)` calls any of them?